# How to rewrite my dataframe transformation with data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a dataframe:

```
ID       value
1      he following object is masked from ‘package:purrr’. R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
2      Attaching package: ‘magrittr’. Natural language support but running in an English locale
2      Attaching package: ‘DT’. Natural language support but running in an English locale
2      Attaching package: ‘anytime’. Natural language support but running in an English locale
3      package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.6.2. Type 'contributors()' for more information
4      Warning messages: type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help
4      Warning messages: 'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help
```

how it can be created:

```
ID <- c(1,2,2,2,3,4,4)
value <- c("he following object is masked from ‘package:purrr’. R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY",
           "Attaching package: ‘magrittr’. Natural language support but running in an English locale",
           "Attaching package: ‘DT’. Natural language support but running in an English locale",
           "Attaching package: ‘anytime’. Natural language support but running in an English locale",
           "package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.6.2. Type 'contributors()' for more information",
           "Warning messages:type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help",
           "Warning messages:'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help")



df <- data.table(ID, value)
```

I transform it with this code:

```
df_patterns <- df  %>% 
  mutate(pattern= stringr::str_extract(value, "\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+"),
         pattern = coalesce(stringr::str_extract(pattern, "^Attaching package:|Warning messages:"),pattern),
         id_type = case_when(ID %in% c(1, 5) ~ "extra_type")
  ) %>%  
  group_by(ID, pattern) %>%
  summarise(example = sample(value,1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(pattern=coalesce(pattern, example))
```

the output is:

```
ID            pattern                  example                                                                                                               id_type                               
1      he following object        he following object is masked from ‘package:purrr’. R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY             extra_type

2      Attaching package:         Attaching package: ‘anytime’. Natural language support but running in an English locale                                     NA

3      package ‘ggplot2’ was      package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.6.2. Type 'contributors()' for more information                               NA

4      Warning messages:          Warning messages:'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help                                                       NA
```

and its desired output. as you see i created new column pattern and grouped data table by it. also i added column example with example of pattern.

how could i rewrite this transformation with data.table? Instead of using mutate and other functions, i want to use data.table's ones. But im not good in it. I tried this, but i don't get what to do next:

```
df_patterns <- df[, c("pattern", "id_type") := list(
  pattern = coalesce(stringr::str_extract(pattern= stringr::str_extract(value, "\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+"), "^Attaching package:|Warning messages:"),pattern= stringr::str_extract(value, "\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+")),
  case_when(ID %in% c(1, 5) ~ "extra_type")), by = ID, pattern]
```

Comment: Could you explain the expected output?

Comment: @zx8754 i added some description

Answer (score 1):

Removing all dependencies except `data.table` the following should match your expected output (but of course varies without setting seed):

```
df_patterns <- 
  copy(df)[, pattern := fcase(
               startsWith(value, "Attaching package:"), "Attaching package:",
               startsWith(value, "Warning messages:"), "Warning messages:",
               rep(TRUE, nrow(df)), sub("((\\S+\\s+){2}\\S+).+", "\\1", value)
             )][, 
                .(
                  example = sample(value, 1), 
                  id_type = fifelse(ID %in% c(1,5),  "extra_type", NA_character_)
                ), 
                by = .(ID, pattern)]


   ID               pattern                                                                                                      example    id_type
1:  1   he following object he following object is masked from ‘package:purrr’. R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY extra_type
2:  2    Attaching package:                           Attaching package: ‘DT’. Natural language support but running in an English locale       <NA>
3:  3 package ‘ggplot2’ was                package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.6.2. Type 'contributors()' for more information       <NA>
4:  4     Warning messages:                                     Warning messages:type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help       <NA>
```

Comment: could not find function "fcase". i don't have that function in data.table package

Comment: and i added column id_type to desired result. i forgot about it in the beginning

Comment: @french_fries You have an old version of `data.table`. To install the newest version use `install.packages('data.table')`. Updated the solution to include `id_type`.